# unique constraint NOT been created on OneToOne

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When using One-To-One relationships in Doctrine, I thought doctrine would usually create a unique constraint on the column? (This will prevent more than one record have the same foreign id, and therefore preventing the relationship ever to be Many-To-One)

I am very sure I have witnessed this behaviour in the past. At the moment the relationship is behaving like a Many-To-One, this is not what I want

Here is an overview of my entities (I am also using table inheritance so those entities have been included also)

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class IplanLayerImage extends ChildIplanLayerImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="IplanLayer", inversedBy="iplanLayerImage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_iplan_layer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    protected $imageIplanLayer;

    /* .................. */
}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="iplan_layer")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class IplanLayer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="IplanLayerImage", mappedBy="imageIplanLayer")
     **/
    protected $iplanLayerImage;

    /* .................. */

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ChildIplanLayerImage extends Upload
{
    /* .................. */
}


/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table("upload")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
*          "photo" = "Photo",
*          "child_photo" = "ChildPhoto",
*          "iplan_layer_image" = "IplanLayerImage",
*          "child_iplan_layer_image" = "ChildIplanLayerImage"
*          })
*/
abstract class Upload
{
    /* ........ */
}
```

I would expect that in the "upload" table (IplanLayerImage entity), the column image_iplan_layer_id would have a unique constraint on it. However, the SQL generated by "app/console doctrine:schema:update" look more like this (the update was ran against an empty database)

```
CREATE TABLE upload (
  id                     INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  image_iplan_layer_id   INT          DEFAULT NULL,
  ...........
  INDEX IDX_17BDE61F8FD952F1 (image_iplan_layer_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE iplan_layer (
  id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  ...........
  INDEX IDX_14E915C1BE04EA9 (job_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

ALTER TABLE upload ADD CONSTRAINT FK_17BDE61F8FD952F1 FOREIGN KEY (image_iplan_layer_id) REFERENCES iplan_layer (id);
```

Any hint to why a unique constraint is not been created?

Symfony 2.6.3

Doctrine 2.5

Comment: you are right I cant see why they are not making it by default unique, My guess goes  for flexibility since you can specify `unique=true` on the `@JoinColumn` annotation

Comment: @zizoujab thanks for the suggestion, it seems adding unique=true it is now creating the unique constraint as I would expect. I thought I had already tried that and the 2nd time around it seems to have worked.

the working line now looks like this
 `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_iplan_layer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, unique=true)`